# Passing position as an argument to Fragment In FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

The getItem() position is not always right! Sometimes it will show 0,1,2,3,4 then if I go back it shows a different position (4,2,3,1,0). What is the proper way to use "position", if I need the position to pass into an arraylist/treemap???

```
02-18 20:07:22.453  11479-11479/com.app E/aaa﹕ position created:0
02-18 20:07:22.453  11479-11479/com.app E/aaa﹕ position created:1
02-18 20:07:29.053  11479-11479/com.app E/aaa﹕ position created:2
02-18 20:07:35.503  11479-11479/com.app E/aaa﹕ position created:0
```

The line:

```
 return SingleCard.newInstance(get_all_cards_as_objects().get(position));
```

Needs the correct position, not the one being rendered into memory! I need the data inside the fragment to change with the actual page position. It will know the data to grab (from the map) based off the actual page position.

```
final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        this.parent_nested_fragment_activity = this;

        pager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()){
            private final int PARENT_COUNT = get_all_cards_as_objects().size();

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
                Object obj = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
                pager.setObjectForPosition(obj, position);
                return obj;
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(CardDealer.this,"Selected page position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("aaa", "position created:" + position);
                    return SingleCard.newInstance(get_all_cards_as_objects().get(position));
            }
```

I have a problem like his, but that answer did not help: 
[FragmentPagerAdapter getItem wrong position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391460/fragmentpageradapter-getitem-wrong-position)

I'm also not sure how to implement this answer into my fragments: [getItem() calling multiple time in FragmentPagerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214063/getitem-calling-multiple-time-in-fragmentpageradapter)

Like this:
[Weird dissappearing Fragments with FragmentPagerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384794/weird-dissappearing-fragments-with-fragmentpageradapter?rq=1)

Basically I've looked into:

```
pager.getCurrentItem();
```

How do I pass this into an already created fragment withing getItem();

```
 return SingleCard.newInstance(get_all_cards_as_objects().get(pager.getCurrentItem()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, the actual fragment I was creating had an issue. I was using a static `int` inside of my SingleCard fragment. Changing it to a non static `int` fixed the problems!

```
   //problem:
     private static int page;
   //solution:
     private int page;

public class SingleCard extends Fragment {
    public static SingleCard newInstance ( int sent_in_position ) {
        SingleCard fragmentFirst = new SingleCard ();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", sent_in_position);
        fragmentFirst . setArguments(args);
        return fragmentFirst;
    }

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    page = getArguments().getInt("position", 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition check if getArguments() is null because if null will return an error

```
page = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("position") : 0;
```